# How to study the monotonicity of $f(x) = \sin 2x$, without using differentiation and continuity.

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

How to study the monotonicity of $f(x) = \sin 2x$, $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$, without using differentiation and continuity.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Do you want to prove that this function is increasing on that interval without using differentiation and continuity?

Comment: How have you defined $\sin$?

Comment: @BernardW No I want to study the monotonicity of the function, exactly as what is written.

Comment: @amsmath  the usual sin.

Comment: @Intuition This does not at all answer my question! How have you defined the sin function? You will have to work with that definition.

Comment: Just look at what sine does as the angle goes around the circle - it should be pretty clear where it is increasing and decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is : $ -1 \leq \sin x \leq  1$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$. $(1)$

You have : $\sin(-\pi)=\sin(\pi)=\sin(0) = 0$  and also $\sin(-\pi/2) = -1,\sin(\pi/2) = 1$. $(2)$

Now, you know that $f(x) = \sin x$ is a continuous function $\forall x \in \mathbb R$. Taking into account this and $(1),(2)$, you can conclude that $f$ is decreasing in the intervals $[-\pi,-\pi/2],[\pi/2,\pi]$ and increasing in the intervals $[-\pi/2,\pi/2].$

Answer (score 1):

The sinus addition formula gives

$$\sin(2x)-\sin(2y)=2\cos(x+y)\sin(x-y)$$

But first let's notice that $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ has period $\pi$.

So we can study on $[0,\pi]$ and to make it even more simple, let's shift the interval by $-\frac{\pi}4$ and study for $x\in[\frac{-\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}4]$.

#### case 1 : $-\frac{\pi}4\le x\le y\le \frac{\pi}4$

$-\frac{\pi}2\le x+y\le\frac{\pi}2\implies\cos(x+y)\ge 0\quad$ and $\quad-\pi\le x-y\le 0\implies\sin(x-y)\le 0$

So $\quad\sin(2x)\le\sin(2y)\quad$ and $\quad f$ is $\nearrow$ on this interval.

#### case 2 : $\frac{\pi}4\le x\le y\le \frac{3\pi}4$

$\frac{\pi}2\le x+y\le\frac{3\pi}2\implies\cos(x+y)\le 0\quad$ and $\quad -\pi\le x-y\le 0\implies\sin(x-y)\le 0$

So $\quad\sin(2x)\ge\sin(2y)\quad$ and $\quad f$ is $\searrow$ on this interval.

#### conclusion:

Completing by $\pi$ periodicity you get $\begin{cases}
f \nearrow \text{ on }[-\pi,-\frac{3\pi}4]\cup[-\frac{\pi}4,\frac{\pi}4]\cup[\frac{3\pi}4,\pi]\\
f \searrow \text{ on }[-\frac{3\pi}4,-\frac{\pi}4]\cup[\frac{\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}4]\\
\end{cases}$